# how to add a duplicate edge in JUNG

Tags: java, jung

I am using JUNG to construct a directed graph. I have two vertices A and B. There is a edge from A to B with a weight of 4. 
I want a duplicate edge from vertex B to A of same weight 4. Is there any way I can do this in JUNG ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many edges with the same weight as you want, as long as you don't use the weight as the edge object itself.  That is, rather than this:

```
graph.addEdge(4, a, b);  // don't do this; you can't tell apart edges with the same weight
```

you can create your own class, e.g.:

```
class MyEdge {
  int weight; 
  public MyEdge(int weight) { this.weight = weight; }
}
...
graph.addEdge(new MyEdge(4), a, b);
```

Your other major option is to have some other way of storing edge weights, e.g., a Map from your edge objects to their respective weights.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense ! Helps a  lot! Thank you so much !